Is this dictionary lookup a google/chrome specific feature or across all of MacOS?
I am trying to open this link in another tab but consistently/repeatably a dictionary lookup of a single word is happening instead

I had seen in other references that this might be due to a keyboard shortcut: but I had disabled that already weeks ago:

So then why is this lookup happening and how can it be disabled?

I’m certain that’s the standard contextual menu on macOS for selected text. I’m not familiar with chrome, so perhaps this will help you directly or to edit in more details? It may also be worthwhile to check several sites in case yours is injecting content past what you select.
